# Table is not working

Tags: asp.net

I am using table in asp.net webform

I am trying like this :

```
<div>
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
        <tr>
            <td> asdf </td>
            <td> asdf </td>
        </tr>
    </asp:Table>
</div>
```

Its not working .

> asdf asdf Error Creating Control -
>   UpdatePanel1System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRowCollection must have
>   items of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow'. 'tr' is of type
>   'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing ASP.NET server-side controls with standard HTML.  Take a look at the [examples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.aspx):

```
<asp:Table id="Table1" runat="server"
    CellPadding="10" 
    GridLines="Both"
    HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            Row 0, Col 0
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            Row 0, Col 1
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            Row 1, Col 0
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            Row 1, Col 1
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

The immediate child tags for an `asp:Table` in this case are `asp:TableRow` (the server-side control), not `tr` (the HTML tag).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `<tr>`, `<td>` or `<th>` tags within an `<asp:Table>` as you would with a standard HTML `<table>`  Instead you must use ASP.NET table tags as follows:

```
<asp:Table runat="server">  
  <asp:TableHeaderRow runat="server">  
    <asp:TableHeaderCell>Header 1</asp:TableHeaderCell>  
    <asp:TableHeaderCell>Header 2</asp:TableHeaderCell>  
    <asp:TableHeaderCell>Header 3</asp:TableHeaderCell>  
  </asp:TableHeaderRow>  
  <asp:TableRow runat="server"> 
    <asp:TableCell>Value 1</asp:TableCell>  
    <asp:TableCell>Value 2</asp:TableCell>  
    <asp:TableCell>Value 3</asp:TableCell>  
  </asp:TableRow>  
</asp:Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The rows and cells have to be the asp.net server control versions.

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
          <table ID="Table1" runat="server">
                    <tr>
                        <td> asdf </td>
                        <td> asdf </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```