# ASP.NET Web Forms access control on page from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have to modify an old ASP.NET Web Forms project.  I have a page with a table that I need to load data on from code behind.  When the page loads I want to initialize it for datatables from JavaScript.  The problem is when the JavaScript runs, the table is not loaded into the page yet, because it is runat = server.  I've tried putting the script block in a div with a runat=server figuring they might appear at the same time. No luck.  I know the script works because if I remove runat=server from the table, they load at the same time and it gets initialized as a datatables table.  I've also tried RegisterStartupScript and RegisterScriptBlock, neither of them work. If I can't get this to work I'm ok with loading the data some other way.  The only reason I needed the table as runat server is to load data from code behind

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     st();
     function st() {
            console.log('load datatable');
            $('[name = "employeeChangeHistory"]').DataTable();

            }

   </script>
     <table runat="server" name="employeeChangeHistory"  
       ..... 
    </table>
```

Comment: Are you actually able to load data into that table as it is? Wondering if you've tried that yet. (If it's already sorted out with Adriani6's answer, ignore this.)

Comment: Hi, I'm still having the same problem.  Basically I can either take off the runat server and the javascript works because the page is loaded with the javascript and the control at the same time, or put it in and the table is loaded after the javascript.  I can see that in the dynamic page debugger in VS.  The script loads, then the table

Comment: Ok. To be honest, the question is confusing. It kind of sounds like you need two tables, one loaded from code-behind, one loaded (created) from js (DataTables). Or maybe just one and you're sending data from code-behind to js then loading DataTables? If you could put the whole flow into your question it would help a lot. Add the outline of the code-behind (triggered by button or page load or whatever) then the outline of getting data, plus where the js is getting data from; everything that shows the order of "events".

Comment: Fwiw, I use DataTables on one of my pages and i create the entire html table -- with data -- as a string in code-behind and send it to js where it's applied to an element on the page.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion.  Yes I have one table declared in html.  I simply want to call datatables init on that table when the page loads.  I can do this just fine as long as I don't have the runat=server on that table.  As soon as I do that, the js doesn't find the table because when the js fires, the table is not in the page yet.  I can see this very behavior in Visual Studio with dynamic script debugging.  I need runat server because I don't know how else to populate the table from codebehind.  I hope that helps

Comment: The scenario you describe where you create an entire html table as a string and send it to js on the page, that sounds very interesting

Comment: Ah. So the problem is really the timing. You said that too... What if you put `defer` on the script? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp. **Also/or** make sure your script is at the end of the page. In your question it's *before* the html. If it's first, the table tag *is not on the page yet, but the script is looking for it and can't find it*.

Comment: Hi @wazz I put the script at the bottom and it seemed to help. thanks for your help!  I hope I helped my marking your comments as helpful, as I already had to mark the original poster as answer

Comment: Thanks, I added the comment as an answer. I think you can vote for any number of answers that help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

You can't have the `table` html tag render as an ASP.NET control as it isn't one.

You should be looking at using [asp:Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table?view=netframework-4.8) instead:

`<asp:Table runat="server" ID="employeeChangeHistory">`

and calling your javascript using

`$("#<%= employeeChangeHistory.ClientID %>").DataTable();`

Comment: oh, I was just about to try out your previous solution.  The table works as runat server just fine

Comment: looks like I have to redeclare the table differently as shown here?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475335/table-is-not-working

Comment: @PatrickGoode Correct. This is because like I said, you can't have the table html tag render as an ASP.NET control. That's why ASP.Net controls are pre-fixed with `<asp:<control>>`. Once you change it to an ASP table, you'll be able to use the above javascript to target the element by ID.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  I made the changes above, however the same issue still persists.  So the problem isn't not knowing what the id of the table is, Its that the script runs and the table is not rendered yet.  I've tried inside document ready, I don't think its firing at the right time.

Comment: @PatrickGoode No, it isn't. The table will render BEFORE that javascript runs. The page is rendered on the server and then it's sent to the client, where as javascript is ran on the client. Edit your question with the code you currently have.

Comment: Youre' right.  I ended up getting the script to recognize the table.  I changed something, not sure what it was.  thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `defer` on the script. w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp.

Also/or make sure your script is at the end of the page. In your question it's before the html. Script is read completely by the browser before moving on, so if it's first, the script looks for html tags it needs, but won't find them because they're not on the page yet. Putting the script at the end helps (but doesn't guarantee) that the script can find any html it looks for. (`Defer` helps to guarantee that the page is fully loaded before the script.)